# Burninate the "highscores" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

There are currently [49 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/highscores) with the [highscores](/questions/tagged/highscores) tag, which seem to be exclusively on the topic of implementing assorted high score tables for games. To my mind, this tag isn't a great fit for SO as it's describing a feature of an end product rather than the technology or the programming concepts required to implement it.

Should we burninate it?

**EDIT:** There are also 17 questions tagged [highscore](/questions/tagged/highscore) (singular), which I also propose that we include.

Comment: Is there an appropriate tag this can be merged into?

Comment: @Robert game-development, I guess. I don't think [scores] is a candidate, because it seems to be in good use for tagging questions relating the the Facebook Scores API. (And if it weren't it would be a candidate for burnination too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done: @Robert Harvey has merged the tags [highscore](/questions/tagged/highscore) and [highscores](/questions/tagged/highscores) into [game-development](/questions/tagged/game-development) and also set up tag synonyms.